# APA location/address of publisher vs location of conference

Tags: citations, writing

I need some clarification of the parameter `location` specified in the APA manual regarding papers published in the proceedings of conferences. Virtually all online data banks for papers that I came across give the location where the conference took place but not the location of the publisher. Some times I have a hard time finding out what the latter is sometimes I can't find it at all.

The manual gives this example:

> **39. Proceedings published in book form**
>
> Katz, I., Gabayan, K., & Aghajan, H. (2007). A multi-touch surface
>   using multiple cameras. In J. Blanc-Talon, W. Philips, D. Popescu, & P.
>   Scheunders (Eds.), *Lecture Notes in ComputerScience: Vol. 4678.
>   Advanced Concepts for intelligent Vision Systems* (pp. 97—108). Berlin,
>   Germany: Springer-Verlag. doi:
>   10.1 007/978-3-5407460729

Does `location` really mean the formal/legal location of the publisher? What if I can't find out what it is because the publisher does not mention it on their website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "location" means the venue of the conference, where it was formally organized. This location is needed to conflict when there are two different conferences with the same name organized in two different locations.

The location that shows in your example "Germany" is most probably the place where the proceeding is published. This location is not very required.